# RegEx for replacing all occurrences of character between two delimiters

Tags: php, regex, delimiter

I need the help of some RegEx gods here, as I've tried for two hours and can't wrap my head around this:

Sample source:

```
DisplayText="cf font=&quot;Arial" size="10" complexscriptsfont="Arial&quot; complexscriptssize="10" asiantextfont=&quot;Arial" fontcolor="595959"">
```

I want to replace all instances of " with `&quot;` but only if these are inside the enclosing ". I.e. the above should become:

```
DisplayText="cf font=&quot;Arial&quot; size=&quot;10&quot; complexscriptsfont=&quot;Arial&quot; complexscriptssize=&quot;10&quot; asiantextfont=&quot;Arial&quot; fontcolor=&quot;595959&quot;">
```

The exact structure of the text inside DisplayText is unknown and varies all the time, but whatever the case, we don't want " within the outer ". As you can see, the outer " are left untouched. This should only occur in strings starting with DisplayText=" and ending with ">.

So finding the strings that need editing is easy:

```
/DisplayText\="(.*?)"\>/
```

Now we just need to replace " with `&quot;` *within* $1 only.

This is for PHP.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately using htmlentities won't work, as this string is embedded in a much larger XML file of which we don't want to convert any entities. Our only option is preg_replace.

Comment: You can't extract the string, run the function, then replace the string?

Comment: No that's not that easy. You need `/DisplayText="[^>]*?">/`. Also try `preg_replace('#(="|\G(?!\A))([^">]*)"(?!\s*>)#', '$1$2;quote', $str);`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/abwGFw/1

Comment: Almost there! However, this (at least the preg_replace, not the live demo) also converts strings with only the outer " and without any `&quot`: `<?xml version="1.0">` becomes `<?xml version="1.0;quote?>`. How do we prevent that? Also the ;quot in the preg_replace probably needs to be &quot; else I get literal ;quot in the output.

Answer (score 2):

In the end this worked!

```
$postproc = preg_replace('#(DisplayText="|\G(?!\A))([^">]*)"(?!\s*>)#', '$1$2&quot;', $postproc);
```

So I just had to add DisplayText to prevent the RegEx from becoming overzealous and start touching other tags in the XML.

Thank you all and especially revo for that suggestions I just seem not to be able to upvote revo's comment?

Answer (score 0):

How about this code:

https://3v4l.org/6qHhb

```
$str = 'DisplayText="cf font=&quot;Arial" size="10" complexscriptsfont="Arial&quot; complexscriptssize="10" asiantextfont=&quot;Arial" fontcolor="595959"">';
$splitted = explode('"', $str);
$splittedSize = count($splitted);
$result = $splitted[0].'"'.implode('&quot;',array_slice($splitted,1,$splittedSize-2)).$splitted[$splittedSize-1].'"';
echo $result;
```